# Getting (null) on the first element in JSON

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, httpwebrequest

I want to log the first element with his subject. If I call the method using [self doRequest] in `viewDidload`, it works perfectly.

But if I call the method in a if- statement, it returns (null).

Code:

```
//Do request method
  NSString *host = @"api.blazor.nl";
if(![host hasPrefix:@"http://"] || ![host hasPrefix:@"https://"])
{
    host = [@"http://" stringByAppendingString:host];
}



NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", host]] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0f];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSString *publickey = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                       stringForKey:@"publicKey"];

NSString *privatekey = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"privateKey"];


NSLocale* currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString* currentTime = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale:currentLocale];

[request setValue:currentTime forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-api-time"];
[request setValue:publickey forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-api-public"];
[request setValue:privatekey forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-api-private"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSURLSessionDataTask *urlSessionDataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

            UIAlertController *alertViewController=   [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"An error happened" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction* closeAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
            [alertViewController addAction:closeAction];
            [self presentViewController:alertViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        });

        return;
    }

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;


    NSInteger success = 1;


    NSError *serializeError = nil;

    NSDictionary *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                              error:&serializeError];



    success = [jsonData2[@"ERROR"] integerValue];


    if((long)[httpResponse statusCode] == 200){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"logged_in"];
    }

    if (success == 0) {


        NSLog(@"%@", jsonData2[@"notifications"][0][@"thread"][@"subject"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", jsonData2);

        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]);



    }else{


    }

}];
[urlSessionDataTask resume];

    //if statement

    if(count < someNumber) {

         [self doRequest];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:someNumber forKey:@"count"];

    } else {
         NSLog(@"Number not samller then someNumber");
    }

}

//Json:
notifications =     (
                {
            content = "has quoted you in";
            created = "2017-06-22T12:12:04+00:00";
            id = "68b87954-77ae-4202-bb2f-2417a974fa57";
            "reply_id" = 79811;
            thread =             {
                id = 3294;
                subject = "Ik erger me aan..... deel 2";
            };
            "thread_id" = 3294;
            "users_from" =             {
                username = Moe;
            };
        }
    );
}
```

What's wrong with the code?

Thanks.

Comment: `doRequest` That's an async call? It returns nulls where?

Comment: I think you need to explain little bit more. its not exactly what you are asking about

Comment: could you please post more code? it's not clear

Comment: add your json format and doRequest method.

Comment: Is `if(count < someNumber)` related to `jsonData2`? If YES, `dataTaskWithRequest:` is ASYNCHRONE. So `NSLog(@"%@", jsonData2);` will be called AFTER `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:someNumber forKey:@"count"];`.

Comment: I fixed it by doing the if statement in the doRequest method.